# Is there is a way to generate "simple" url with @Url.Action?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I wants to generate a link in my view to action "Index" of "Model" controller with id so I use the following code: 
`@Url.Action("", "Model", new { id = 531} )`
As expected it generates url like `/Model/Index/531`which unfortunately seems to be complicated.
Actually it works well, but I want to generate url like `/Model?id=531` coz it looks simplier to me. 
So my question is "**Is it possible to generate such type of url with razor markup?**"
I've heard that it's a bad practice to manually generate url in markup, but don't remember why, so I'd be wondered if someone will highlight Cons of this approach as it seems simpler way to solve my problem.

Comment: Remove Id from default route, in global.asax file

Comment: Actually, the first one is better (SEO). The url is formed based on your route configuration, are you sure you don't like your route configuration? IMO you should start liking it :).